# Problem moving image with search bar animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a search bar when focused moves up with an animation
I want the same with image placed on top of the search bar...
so that when we click on search bar image gets smaller and move in top left corner and search bar moves up in sync animation.

right now i have managed to move search bar but stuck at image part...
I am trying to detect focus with JS and then make transition for image too but margin-left and margin bottom is not working...

Can anyone help to complete it? please

```js
var input = document.getElementById("SearchBar");
var homeImage = document.getElementById("homeImage");
input.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    homeImage.classList.add('horizTranslate');
});
```

```css
#SearchBar {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
    width: 40%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('search-icon.svg');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-color: #ffaf7b;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    transition: width 0.8s ease, top 0.5s ease, border-color 0.5s ease;
}

#homeImage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28%;
    left: 45%;
}

#SearchBar:focus {
    width: 90%;
    top: 22%;
    border-color: #ff512f;
}


.horizTranslate {
    transition: 3s;
    margin-right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="SearchBar" placeholder="XXXXX...">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" src="pattern-img.png" alt="Girl in a jacket" id="homeImage"><script src="ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/rockg688/pen/GRgLBWX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with no javascript

CSS:

```
#SearchBar {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("search-icon.svg");
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-color: #ffaf7b;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  transition: width 0.8s ease, top 0.5s ease, border-color 0.5s ease;
}

#homeImage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  left: 45%;
  transition: 1s;
}

#SearchBar:focus {
  width: 90%;
  top: 22%;
  border-color: #ff512f;
  transition: 1s;
  margin-right: 50%;
}

#SearchBar:focus+#homeImage {
  top: 0;
  left: 80%;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks But why height and width is not animating when we try to add width and height in focus + part

Comment: because I didn't change the height or width. you can put whatever you want there and it will change

Comment: Yes i did add the width and height but they are not smoothly changing size...
[here](https://codepen.io/rockg688/pen/GRgLBWX)

Comment: for a transition to affect you need to set the style parameters in both selectors. if you will set the width and the height in the first `#homeImge` selector the transition will have a reference and work.